# Jquery ajax success multiple functions

Tags: jquery

I'm loading images in the DOM using ajax.

Once the data is loaded, on success i then call the function which creates the html for the page including the images just brought in from the ajax call.

What I want to do is lazy load the images but cannot figure out where I need to add the code to bind the images to lazy load

Here's the ajax code which calls the next function on success

```
$.ajax({
        url: apiURL,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {page: page}, 
        success:onLoadData
    });
```

And here's the lazy load function I need to add but where?

```
function(data) {
    $("img.lazy").lazyload({
        effect: "fadeIn"
    });
}
```

Comment: what does your json look like?

Comment: Why not at the end of onLoadData?